# ASP.NET Web Pages with Razor

Tags: asp.net

how to get the name of select tag and use to if condition here is my code:

```
@{
     var size="";
     if(Request.Form["cboSize"] == "Extra Small (XS)"){
       size = "Extra Small (XS)";
     }
     ...
 }
<select name="cboSize">
     <option value="xs">Extra Small (XS)</option>
     <option value="s">Small (S)</option>
     <option value="m">Medium (M)</option>
     <option value="l">Large (L)</option>
     <option value="xl">Extra Large (XL)</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your select node in a form to get its value from `Request.Form["cboSize"]`:

```
<form method="POST">
    <select name="cboSize">
        <option value="xs">Extra Small (XS)</option>
        <option value="s">Small (S)</option>
        <option value="m">Medium (M)</option>
        <option value="l">Large (L)</option>
        <option value="xl">Extra Large (XL)</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then in your code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    var size = Request.Form["cboSize"];
    //do something with it asyncronously

    return RedirectToPage($"/Details/{size}");
}
```